# How do I disable an Outlook 2013 add-in without starting Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, outlook-addin

All the guides I've found online start with "go to the *Tools* menu". My problem is that Outlook 2013 will not start at all because it gets stuck at start-up while it tries to load the TeamViewer add-in.

How can I disable the TeamViewer add-in?

Comment: I don't have a windows machine in front of me, but if I remember correctly the add-ons are installed in the folder `C:\Users\fardelian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns`. Of course fardelian should be the actual username. You can move/delete an add-ons from there to try to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the TeamViewer settings to disable the TeamViewer's Outlook addin. Go to options, advance, then disable outlook addin near the bottom of the list.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be available anymore in TeamViewer 10.

Answer (score 21):

Start outlook in safe mode: `outlook.exe /safe`

> If you are having problems with a Microsoft Office program, you may be able to use User-Initiated Safe mode to make it possible to run the program.

[More info on Office's SafeMode here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook-help/work-with-office-safe-modes-HP010140792.aspx#BM2)

Answer (score 2):

I read alternatives about running outlook as administrator. The shortcut I had on my taskbar was not a shortcut to Outlook its self, but some meta-information about it. Eventually I found the `OUTLOOK.EXE` file somewhere in `C:\Program Files` and rick-clicked it and ran it as administrator. That immediately found and disabled the culprit, without even asking me. I assume this is similar to running it in safe mode.

Comment: I've found that if you wait awhile, it will figure out that they're not responding even in user mode at startup.

Comment: I personally wouldn't do this - if it was an actually malicious addin (as opposed to a crashing addin by a legitimate company), it's possible that it would have used those administrator privileges to further compromise your system.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the TeamViewer add-in files and Outlook will load and show it as inactive. Go to: Program Files (or Program Files (x86))\TeamViewer\Version9\outlook

There are four files in this folder and three of the names start with "TeamViewerMeetingAddIn"
 
I renamed these by putting 1 as the first character, "1TeamViewerMeetingAddIn"
 
When I restarted Outlook it loaded up with no problem.